# How should I change the theme color with LESS and jquery by click on a link?

Tags: jquery, html, css, less

I use LESS, and have several variables for different colors:

```
@LightBlue: #0088CC;
@DarkPink: #C71C77;
@LightGreen: #76B51B;

@DefaultThemeColor: @LightBlue;
```

also, I have links for the colors, so when the user click on each link the theme color changes.

```
<ul>
    <li class="light-blue"><a href="#"> light blue </a></li>
    <li class="light-green"><a href="#"> light green </a></li>
    <li class="dark-pink"><a href=""> dark pink </a></li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know how I can do this with LESS and jquery?

Comment: do you want to change the color of link after click on it?

Comment: LESS is being compiled to CSS files. You shuld create various CSS themes and then after click reloading it.

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar, no, I want to change the the color of entire theme when the user click on each link

Comment: Unless you have server side compliation of LESS into new CSS files..this is not possible..at least AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make seperate CSS files for each theme. Then the code could follow as such:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjgE2/1/ <-- Demo

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="light-blue"><a href="#"> light blue </a></li>
    <li class="light-green"><a href="#"> light green </a></li>
    <li class="dark-pink"><a href="#"> dark pink </a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $('ul li').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // Files named the same as the class
        var cssFile = $(this).attr('class'); 
        // Remove all theme styles
        $('head link[href="/styles/light-blue.css"], head link[href="/styles/styles/light-green.css"], head link[href="/styles/styles/dark-pink.css"]').remove();
        // Apply the clicked style
        $("<link/>", { 
           rel: "stylesheet",
           type: "text/css",
            href: "/styles/" + cssFile + ".css"
        }).appendTo("head");
    });
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you @wrxsti, you're right. you're solution works. I can do this with pure css. but the problem is that I don't know how to create the new css theme file with less. should I just change the color variable in the new less file?

Comment: To be perfectly honest I've never used LESS, but it sounds very similar to a preprocessor I used with nodeJS. You should be able to just make the one variable color and change the value per file. Hope that helps!